# How to run Unit Tests in VS as a different user?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, authentication

I'm a contractor doing some unit tests that use Windows authentication to hit a test server in a different domain.  I've been running my tests on my clients VM and everything has been running fine since I'm on their network, and using my login credentials on their domain to run the unit tests.  Unfortunetly the VM is extremely slow, (it took 30 minutes for the server to reboot, and for me to bring up the 14 project solution) and I decided to try and run VS on my laptop.  I was able to get it to build just fine, but when I go to run my unit tests, It errors out when it attempts to access the test server since I'm running as myself on my laptop which is not in their domain.

Is there any way to run the unit tests as a different user?

I tried using C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /netonly /user:theirDomain\uid "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" to run the tests, but it doesn't work (I'm guessing because the unit tests actually run as QTAgent32.exe that it doesn't work).  I have been able to use the same command for SQL Server Manager to connect to their SQL server.

Another option may be to figure out a way to trust my user credentials on their domain on my laptop, but that isn't working either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the unit tests directly using the command line application mstest.exe.  This is what VS is doing under the hood.  In conjunction with runas.exe, I think should completely solve your problem.

Reference for mstest.exe:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182489(v=vs.80).aspx

Edit:
I'd just like to say that in the interest of efficiency I think the ideal solution here would be for their sys admins to create a domain account for you to use.

Comment: I have a domain account to use.  But since neither domain trusts the other, I can't run VS using their account because my computer won't trust it, and I can't get authenticated to the server because they don't trust my domain... I am an admin on my laptop, so one would think I would be able trust their domain so one of their accounts could run on my laptop, I just haven't been able to figure that out either.

Comment: Sorry, what I *meant* to say was try joining your laptop to their domain.  It goes without saying you probably need their permission to do so: http://www.petri.co.il/join-a-domain-in-windows-7.htm

Comment: So If I join their domain, I'll have to switch back to my domain later?

Comment: I've got a work around using a batch file to perform the run as /netonly function, and then using System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() to allow me to debug...  Man it's annoying that I have to enter my credentials each time though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have domain account - you can raise VPN connection or add your laptop to their domain.

Comment: @Daryl Make VPN connection. I'm translating it literally from Russian ))  http://serverfault.com/questions/227587/how-to-join-a-domain-over-vpn. Once you've made VPN - you are in their domain on your laptop.

Comment: Not quite understanding the issue here.  I'm already physically connected to their LAN.  My laptop is in a different domain, but the server I'm hitting in my unit test is using windows authentication and  I can't run Visual Studio on my machine with their Domain account.